# ~ no longer takes me to my home directory

Tags: server, command-line, bashrc

I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu (and linux in general) and since I have a machine spare, I have Ubuntu Server (terminal only) installed on one of my machines. I've recently started playing around with my dotfiles, however it seems I've messed something up as changing directory to '~' no longer presents me with the expected user's home directory!

The .bashrc file that's in my dotfiles directory then points to a ".env" file at ~/bin/dotfiles/.env which contains the following:

```
export EDITOR="nano"
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export home="/home/joe/"
export dotfiles="/home/joe/bin/dotfiles"
```

Does anyone have any ideas to restore the tilde to my user's home location?

Comment: With what user your are trying to cd ~?

Comment: The only user on the machine ("joe") - it worked absolutely fine until I messed around wit the .bashrc file.

Comment: If you put it back under joe's home does it works? I have the suspicion that configuration files for your profile and applications had to be under your home.

Comment: Put what back? I replaced the files - I can't put it back :P (I have a feeling that it was stored in that file though)

Comment: You said you changed it to . ~/bin/dotfiles/.bashrc
you can mv /home/joe/bin/dotfiles/.bashrc /home/joe/.bashrc

Comment: My configuration in my home directory simply points towards the .bashrc in my dotfiles directory so that's not the problem. Everything I've specified works fine - however ~ doesn't lead me to home...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

~ takes you to whatever the variable `$HOME` points to.

Therefore, run

```
echo $HOME
```

to see the value of $HOME. 
Then find where $HOME is set to that inappropriate directory and fix it.